# Putting into TreeMap - strange behavior

Tags: java, treemap

I would by grateful for any advice. I have this code:

```
TreeMap<Date, Double> predictPoints = new TreeMap<Date, Double>();
while(iterator_time.hasNext()) {
            Date time = iterator_time.next();

            if (count < obs.toList().size()) {
                count++;tmp1++;
                continue;
            } else {            
                for (int j = 0; j <= degreePolynom; j++) {
                    predictConsumption += coeff[j] * Math.pow(time.getTime(), j);
                }
                predictPoints.put(time, predictConsumption);
                predictConsumption = 0.0;
                count++;tmp2++;
            }

        }
```

I iterate through `Vector` and in this vector is 35036 number. `tmp1` and `tmp2` variables are just for check. 80% of data are skipped (if block, obs.toList().size() is 35036) and the rest of data (20%) I use. Problem: I iterate in `else` block 7007 times but in `predictPoints` is only 7003 items. This problem does not occur if I use less data. If I use `TreeMap` without `Date`, for example `TreeMap<Integer, Double>` then I have 7007 items in map and it is right. Every number is unique - I tested it.
Where are 4 lost items? :-(

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Unrelated, but why (oh why) are you using `Vector`? It has been virtually deprecated since Java 1.2 back in 1998. They even suggested using `ArrayList` in the javadoc to [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html).

Comment: @DmitryP. `containsKey` has only one parameter, and since map value (`predictConsumption`) is never null, simply checking return value of `put` is faster than using extra call to `containsKey`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maps don't support duplicate keys, so if you add `7007` items to a map, but only end up with `7003` items, then `4` of the items had duplicate key and *replaced* the previous value.

Check the return value of `put()` to check if it replaced an existing value.

Comment: I know but it is strange, because keys are dates and they are unique. There is no other choice? But I'm going to try value of put() definitely. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielHerbrych `Vector` (and it's `ArrayList` replacement) allows duplicate values, so it can have two values with the same timestamp.

Comment: thank you, you are right... there is 4 duplicates...! thank you very much

Comment: @DanielHerbrych If the answer was useful, please click up-arrow on left (tooltip: "This answer is useful"). If the answer is what you were looking for, also like the check-mark to "accept" the answer. That way others can see the question has been answered in an acceptable way.